# Meteor app does not update Meteor.settings after a hot-code-push on Android app

Tags: cordova, meteor

I have an app deployed on Galaxy and I have mobile versions (Android and iOS) as well.

I just noticed today that if I just change my Meteor.settings file and redeploy to Galaxy, this does trigger a hot-code-push on my mobile devices as expected.
The problem is that when the app reloads after the hot-code-push process is finished, I don't see the new values from Meteor.settings on Android. The app reloads but the Meteor.settings files is still the old one.
To see the new values I have to completely close the mobile app and open it again. This probably means that the reload process does not reload the Meteor.settings file as well.

Does any one else can confirm this problem? This is bad because I frequently just change my Meteor.settings file and I don't want to be forced to launch an update on Google Playstore everytime. I need to rely on hot-code-push.

I'm using the latest Meteor Version 1.5.1.

Answer (score 1):

Good day.

I also experienced a similar issue. I found that the best way to ensure the updated code is loaded and settings updated is to follow-up the process below:

1. Deploy the New Code (i.e.  DEPLOY_HOSTNAME=yourServer-deploy.meteor.com meteor deploy yourAppDomain.com --settings settings.json
2. Stop the Start the App: to do this go to the settings tab in your Meteor Galaxy dashboard and click Stop App and then click restart the app.

This should get things going when you are testing your app or in a pre-defined maintenance window.

Good luck.